# Use javascript to parse URL (not querystring) folder structure domain/parseThis/

Tags: parsing, url

I know how to parse the query string but I am getting sent a format of :  domainName/variable/somethingElseIDontCareAbout

I need to grab that middle portion and so I can see what it says... any help?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original url is something like `http://domainname.com/variable/else`, you can use this:

```
document.location.href.split("/")[3]
```

If not, just change the number in the brackets.

Comment: nice!  that makes sense! woot!