# Javascript String Manipulation - URLs

Tags: javascript

I need to extract the device name from this URL using javascript:

http://store.myshop.com/my-shop-mobile/pay-monthly-phones/samsung-galaxy-j3-white/samsung-galaxy-j3-white-tariffs.html?filters=1

So I am just left with "samsung-galaxy-j3-white"

Parts of this URL are variable, for example it could also look like this:

http://store.myshop.com/my-shop-mobile/pay-as-you-go-phones/galaxy-j3-white/samsung-galaxy-j3-white-tariffs.html?filters=1

But it is always after the 3rd "/" after the domain.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see why your question is voted down and possibly closed. HINT: Post relevant code

Comment: I found another question on here which mentioned remove prefix, but that only works for the first part: http://store.myshop.com/my-shop-mobile/

Comment: hint: `str.split("/")` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278106/use-javascript-to-parse-url-not-querystring-folder-structure-domain-parsethis

Comment: Using @cYrixmorten hint, the device name seems to always be the [5]th element within the array. Seen here: http://i.imgur.com/u19YYou.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple JavaScript array methods like `split` and `reverse` is plenty to solve this.

```js
[
  'http://store.myshop.com/my-shop-mobile/pay-monthly-phones/samsung-galaxy-j3-white/samsung-galaxy-j3-white-tariffs.html?filters=1',
  'http://store.myshop.com/my-shop-mobile/pay-as-you-go-phones/galaxy-j3-white/samsung-galaxy-j3-white-tariffs.html?filters=1'
].forEach(function(a) {
  console.log(a.split('/').reverse()[0].split('.html')[0]);
});
```

Comment: I usually write my answer code in the console in my browser, so it got left in ^^
I'll remove it.